# How to get access to the application config file from filter?

Tags: java, playframework

I have a filter that filtering requests from users and I check if a user has permission for some page or not but some pages all users could visit without any permission and it is URLs I had written on the `application.conf` file and now I need to get access to this `application.conf` file order to get info about whitelist URLs.
My `application.conf` file looks like the following:

```
allowedPathsWithoutAuthentication = ["api/info"]
```

my filter looks like the following:

```
public class PageAccessFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public PageAccessFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {
        // I need to get access to application.conf file right here.
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.badRequest("BBBB"));
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my issue:

```
public class PageAccessFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    private Config config;

    @Inject
    public PageAccessFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {
        config.getString("key");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.badRequest("BBBB"));
    }
}
```